# How to put a blank space in a list?

Tags: python

Example, I want to create this list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, , 5]
```

How do I put in the blank space in between `3` and `5`? I want to make a game of Hangman with it, and the blank space will be filled in by the player. The list itself will contain the Hangman question that the player will need to solve.

Comment: a better question is why do you want to?

Comment: You can put e.g. `None` in, but you can't have it "empty".

Comment: Another thing is you can have the list and use the insert function to insert a value into the index you want.

Comment: If hangman is the intent, I assume it's going to be a list of characters. You could use ``'_'`` so that when printed via `print(''.join(chrs))` you'll get something like `'W_R_'` if ``chrs = ['W','_','R','_']``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't leave an "empty space" in a list; each index has to contain *something*. In general, an "empty" index would be indicated by some sentinel value, often `None`.

For a game like Hangman, you will probably have your own empty space character, e.g. an underscore `"_"`:

```
word = ["h", "e", "_", "_", "o"]
```

This allows you to easily `print` the `word`, showing the user where the blanks are:

```
>>> print " ".join(word)
h e _ _ o
```